# What is the purpose of module.require?

Tags: node.js

The documentation for `module.require` states that:

> The `module.require` method provides a way to load a module as if `require()` was called from the original module.

The documentation is really opaque about the purpose of this. When, how, and why would I ever need to use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`module.require` is primarily used by Node.js' module system itself, specifically by [`require()`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require):

```
console.log(require.toString());
//  function require(path) {
//    return self.require(path);
//  }
```

In this case, [`self` refers to the current `module` object](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.18/lib/module.js#L374-L381). But, you could use `module.require()` just as you use `require()`:

```
console.log(require('./foo') === module.require('./foo')); // true
```

And, if you have a reference to the `module` object from another file, such as from [`require.main`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module), you can use it to specify paths relative to that module.

```
$ node foo.js
```

```
// foo.js
var bar = require('./src/bar');
```

```
// src/bar.js
var baz = require.main.require('./lib/baz'); // relative to `foo.js`
```

Comment: Could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624017/why-require-main-require-resolve-is-undefined? thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

It provides a nice way to keep your code clean and modular. Basically, you'd write your methods as objects and export them, and then they can be loaded into another file in short hand by requiring them.

Comment: This is a description of `require()` not `module.require()` which is different, with a different purpose (which I am still in the dark on).