# Why require.main.require.resolve is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require, commonjs

## The question

Whitin the scope of a node.js module there is a `module` object meant to be *a reference to the current module*, a `require` function meant to *require modules* and a `require.resolve` function meant to *look up the location of a module but rather than load the module just return the resolved filename*.

If there is a `module.require` as there is a `require`, why there isn't a `module.require.resolve` as there is a `require.resolve`?

Or potentially the same thing: **Why `module.require !== require`**?

```
console.log('is require.main the same as module?');
console.log( require.main === module );

console.log('does module have a require property being a function?');
console.log( 'function' === typeof module.require );

console.log('is module.require the same as require.main.require?')
console.log( module.require === require.main.require );

console.log('is module.require the same as require?')
console.log( module.require === require );

console.log('why not?')
```

### Notes

1. On the code example, assume a file called `something.js` executed through `node something.js`.
2. Please do not answer *because the current implementation is that*, the question is if there is really a reason to justify the current design/implementation/behaviour.
3. For those wondering about a use case, I want to resolve an identifier as if `require.resolve` was called from the main module, so I expected `require.main.require.resolve` not being `undefined`.

## Related on SO

[What is the purpose of module.require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884959/what-is-the-purpose-of-module-require)

## Related documentation

The node.js documentation about globals states [here](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require):

> **`require()`**
>
> To require modules. See the [Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) section. `require` isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.
>
> **`require.resolve()`**
>
> Use the internal `require()` machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.

and [here](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_module):

> **`module`**
> A reference to the current module. In particular `module.exports` is used for defining what a module exports and makes available through `require()`.
>
> `module` isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.

It also states about modules [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id) that:

> **`module.require(id)`**
>
> The module.require method provides a way to load a module as if `require()` was called from the original module.
>
> Note that in order to do this, you must get a reference to the module object. Since `require()` returns the module.exports, and the module is typically only available within a specific module's code, it must be explicitly exported in order to be used.

Comment: Can't your `main` module just wrap its `require.resolve` in a function and pass that to the child that needs access to it? Then you avoid requiring globals like `require.main`. Not to say they are always bad, but it's avoidable in this case. As for "is if there is really a reason to justify the current design/implementation/behaviour.", I don't know, but I also doubt you'll get a specific answer since that code in Node hasn't been touched in 3 years.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yep, currently I'm decorating require and re-assigning it on child modules that need it.

I posted this question because I was wondering if this may be a reason to ask node devs _"Is this a lack on the api design?"_. I don't want they to shoot me for asking about an api that is already frozen ^^ that's the reason to ask feedback from community here.